# How do I get Windows 8 to mount a VHD at startup?

Tags: windows-8, mount, boot, vhd

I have a VHD with a database on it, which I have attached to the database server, which wreaks havoc on the database server after a reboot and the VHD is no-longer mounted.

My searching for this has only brought me answers that mount it *at user login*, but that can happen *long* after the service starts up and notices.

For InfoSec reasons, I've been asked to not copy the database files out of the VHD, so I'm wondering -- is there any viable way to tell Windows 8 to "yes, go ahead and mount this when you start up?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Tool [VHD Attach](http://www.jmedved.com/vhdattach/):

> If so desired you can also use this program to attach various virtual disks upon system 
>   start-up. It is your choice whether this will be done in full-access
>   or read-only mode.

Comment: How to do it from the command line (or a batch script to automate it at startup?)

Comment: @PratyushNalam use this way: http://angler.wordpress.com/2010/03/11/windows-7-auto-mount-vhds-at-startup/